# What were the rules of engagement in military conflicts in the first centuries after Muhammad?

Tags: fiqh, history, jihad, battles

Did Islam have some rules of engagement in military conflicts, concerning women, children and old men? Were there any rules for not touching them after conquering a city or territory?
Did Muhammad have such rules in his expeditions (military conflicts)?

Rules change in time - for example in the Ottoman Empire they took non-Muslim children by force from their parents, periodically, to make them soldiers. So I am interested about the rules in the times of Muhammad and a few centuries after him.

Comment: Yes, you may have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_military_jurisprudence

Comment: Thanks a lot! You should have add that as an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: You're welcome. But link-only answers are discouraged in SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is consensus that it is forbidden to slay non-combatant women and children during war. Additionally, the view of the majority is that it is also forbidden to slay very old men.

This has been cited in the [exegesis](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya190.html) of the following verse; as women, children and old men are from those who do not participate in fighting and killing them is transgression:

> #### وقاتلوا في سبيل الله الذين يقاتلونكم ولا تعتدوا إن الله لا يحب المعتدين
>
> Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you but do not transgress. Indeed. Allah does not like transgressors.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:190](http://quran.com/2/190)</sup>

It is evidenced in ahadith:

> #### فنهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن قتل النساء والصبيان
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade the killing of women and children.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/224) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/29)</sup>

> #### لا تقتلوا شيخا فانيا ولا طفلا ولا صغيرا ولا امرأة
>
> Do not kill a decrepit old man, nor an infant, nor a young child, nor a woman
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/138)</sup>

Similar Instructions from the caliphs Abu Bakr and Umar to the armies they dispatched may be found in e.g. [Sunan al-Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://archive.org/stream/FP78881/skb09#page/n152/mode/2up)  and [Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba](https://archive.org/stream/WAQ63900/musnfsh11#page/n378/mode/2up).

Note that the prohibition is in regard to killing, the Imam had the option to enslave or ransom prisoners of war.